# Is the problem NP-hard?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, np-complete

Let $GF(p) = ({\mathbb Z}_p, +, \times)$ be the Galois field where $p>2$ is prime and let
$$
H=\{1,2,\cdots, \frac{p-1}{2}\}.$$

I need an algorithm (subexponential in terms of $\log_2 p$) that computes at least one element inside the following expression (or, indicate that it is empty)
$$
\bigcap_{i=1}^n a_i H
$$
where $a_1, \cdots, a_n\in {\mathbb Z}_p\setminus \{0\}$ are given as inputs and $aH=\{a\times x\mid x\in H\}$.
I believe that this problem is NP-hard. Can someone give any hints, links, maybe related problems.

Comment: Do you mean to say "that computes at least one element inside the following expression (*) OR provides a proof that the intersection is empty"?

Comment: hello? Did you just post and leave?

Comment: Calculating $a_iH$ takes $O(p)$ operations. This has to be done $n$ times. Then intersection can be done by brute forcing each element, giving all together $O(np)$. Or am I missing something? Or are you looking for something faster?

Comment: @freakish Yes, that is the straightforward. But I need something faster, sub-exponential maybe. In fact, I believe this problem is hopeless, but still maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @Snared that computes at least one element inside the following expression  OR say that the intersection is empty

Comment: For starters, if $a_i=-a_j$ for some $i$ and $j$ then the intersection is empty. So without loss of generality $n\leq\tfrac{p-1}{2}$. For any other pair the intersection is nonempty. Also dividing the $a_i$ by $a_1$ we may assume $a_1=1$.

Comment: This is equivalent to $\{a_1,\ldots a_n\}\subset hH^{-1}$ for some $h\in H$, where $H^{-1} :=\{h^{-1}:\ h\in H\}$. Heuristically each new $a_1$ should cut the search space for $h$ in half...

Comment: @freakish Usually in these problems, $p$ and $a_i$ are provided in binary, which means that the size of the input is $O(n \log p)$, so we are looking for a method which is polynomial in $n \log p$.

Comment: Here’s one crazy idea. If we relax the problem a little and let $p$ be a power of $2$ (maybe a Mersenne prime would suffice, though it seems trickier), then we can consider any number mod $2^n$ as a combination of $n$ truth statements and a question of whether $x\in a_i H$ as whether some Boolean expression on those truth states is true. Maybe it’s possible to express 3SAT in that framework which would show that this variant is NP -Hard (and give motivation to believe that promise p is NP-Hard).

Comment: @Eric Thanks for this idea. 
Though I believe it can be only implemented for $GF(2^n)$. I.e. we choose some irreducible polynomial $p$ of degree $n$ over $GF(2)$ and consider a field modulo $p$. Then we say that our problem is to calculate 
$$
\bigcap_{i=1}^l a_i H
$$
where $H$ is a set of all polynomials $c_0+...+c_{n-1}x^{n-1}\in GF(2^n)$ with $c_0=1$. Though it is a different problem I agree that it is somehow connected with the previous one. 

I will think further on this example.

Comment: Though the latter appears to be in P))

Comment: Err, I was just thinking $\mathbb{Z_{2^n}}$  and to let $H$ be $1$ to $2^{n-1}$. Nothing about your problem requires it to be a field. But yeah, hope the idea helps.